# Transform var @var in fieldname

Tags: mysql, sql

In this query:

```
set @myVars := '';
SELECT C.Id,
      IF((select count(CA.Id) from mytable_2 CA where CA.IdC=C.Id and CA.IdA=10), 
      @myVars:='option_1' , 
      @myVars:='option_2')  as myTempField
FROM mytable_1 C where CONCAT('fied_',@myVars) = 5
```

In this case, I wish that the '**CONCAT('fied_',@myVars)**' became the name of the field that I'm going to query, but it does not work.

Depending on the result of the 'if' the field that will be questioned must be 'field_option_1' or 'field_option_2'

How I can Do It?

Comment: you where condition will never meet

Comment: Why do you want a *varying column name* in the output? Wouldn't that be confusing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra column

```
set @myVars := '';
SELECT
  C.Id,
  IF((select count(CA.Id) from mytable_2 CA where CA.IdC=C.Id and CA.IdA=10), @myVars:='option_1', @myVars:='option_2') as myTempField,
  CONCAT('fied_',@myVars) as AColumn
FROM mytable_1 C
where @myVars = 5
```

This will give you id , myTempField and AColumn

Comment: sorry but your solution don't fix my problem.